# nodejs install and use npm packages

Tags: javascript

Having `nodejs` is *very* nice, but most useful it becomes by accessing all of its packages distributed via `npm`. How can I install a `npm` package?

There is a 3D game engine named `playcanvas` whose package I would like to use and I tried to install it: `npm install -g playcanvas`

But then I still can't use it:

[image: Mathematica can't find global npm package]

Is there any special folder I need to run `npm` in?

Comment: If I run `gr = require("grunt")` I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` so I doubt a big module like _playcanvas_ would load anyway. Smaller modules work, for example with _moment.js_ I can call from Mathematica: `moment = require("moment"); moment().add(7, 'days')` and get an answer. Even if you could load _playcanvas_ , you should expect the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined` because you don't have a WebGL capable front-end to render anything into from the notebook.

Comment: Thanks for trying @flinty but playcanvas is just around 1MB and has a node backend by default (for unit testing and vector/matrix math etc.)

Comment: I can now load it, but I get `ReferenceError: window is not defined` in Mathematica as I explained before. You need to make sure that you have _zeromq_ installed in your home directory _.node_modules_ and _playcanvas_ installed in _node_modules_. Also don't _install -g_, just install locally in the home directory.

Comment: Sorry for misinformation @flinty , you need to execute this code first before loading PlayCanvas: https://gist.github.com/kungfooman/b25416d5e43ca8181753b4e5f487fcff I still didn't get it to work, maybe because I am on Windows 10... will try further

Comment: Running that worked for me and then calling `pc = require("playcanvas")` succeeded and returned a giant association into Mathematica. I'm also running Windows10 so that's not the problem. You need to install playcanvas locally, not globally with -g. It won't load modules for me that are installed to _%appdata%/npm_